# gforth : how to check a variable is set with arg value

Tags: variables, forth, gforth

**gforth** : how to check a variable is set

I currently set a variable from command line like :

```
: functionname
    variable !
;
```

so it gets its value from

```
gforth -e"5" myfile.fs
```

but then I would ensure the variable is set by a default value even if user runs

```
gforth myfile.fs
```

**how can I check variable is set ?** *(then I can give it a default value in a if statement)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I changed method for reading the parameter :

first the function is now like :

```
: valorise_hauteur                                                                                                                                                           
        argc @ 2 < if                           
                cr
                ." no argument using default 5 value"
                5 hauteur !
                cr
        else
                1 arg s>number drop hauteur !
        endif              
;
```

and I can call the full script :

```
gforth myscript.fs 10
```

where 10 is my arg number 1
this method is more command line way to do that & permit to use a default value.

Comment: But this code does not check whether variable is set or not. It checks amount of command line arguments passed to script.

Comment: In fact it does due to the arg test then the variable hauteur is set whatever happens. so it is no more a variable check but a variable force ... yes... ok on this point of view ....  but the real goal having variable hauteur set is respected ... :)